# How to get data from subquery and put into where clause?

Tags: apex, soql, list, conditional

`bundlewithProduct = [SELECT Id, (select Product__c from Product_Quantities__r) FROM Bundle__c WHERE Id =: QBP.Bundle__c];`

from the above mentioned query i am getting the list of bundle with it's Product Quantity

Now, i have one string `ListPrice` and fill this string with ListPrice of selected Product from `bundlewithProduct`

i am bit confuse about how to put `[select Product__c from Product_Quantities__r]` in where clause of the following query

`this.ListPrice = string.ValueOf([SELECT Id, Product2Id, UnitPrice FROM PriceBookEntry where Product2Id =: ______________________);`

can anyone please tell me how to achieve this ?

Comment: How `Product_Quantities__c` and `PriceBookEntry` are related?

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to get `PricebookEntry` records with the sme `Product2Id`, note that you can have ***multiple matches*** since it is a many-to-one relationship (`PricebookEntry` to `Product2`). If you wanted to get the most recently created `PricebookEntry`, for example, you can use the below code. There are a few steps you can take to make it more efficient, but this is the spelled out version.

```
bundlewithProduct = [
    SELECT Id, (
        SELECT Product__c FROM Product_Quantities__r
        ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC LIMIT 1
    )
    FROM Bundle__c WHERE Id =: QBP.Bundle__c
];

Set<Id> productIds = new Set<Id>();
for (Product_Quantity__c child : bundleWithProduct.Product_Quantities__r)
{
    productIds.add(child.Product__c);
}

List<PricebookEntry> mostRecentEntry = [
    SELECT UnitPrice FROM PricebookEntry
    WHERE Product2Id IN :productIds
];

Decimal mostRecentPrice;
if (!mostRecentEntry.isEmpty)
{
    mostRecentPrice = mostRecentEntry.UnitPrice;
}
```